# FastReport 4 Current page sum

Tags: fastreport

I am using FastReport with Delphi.  Now, I need to display sum value of each page. 
I mean, I need sum value for current page on each page of the report.

How can I achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Sum value of what - numeric column (columns) or something else? Thanks.

Comment: yes, SUM value of a numeric column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use `"Page Footer"` band and `"Text"` object with `SUM()` function for that purpose.

Steps to follow:

- put a `PageFooter` band (`TfrxPageFooter`) on you report page
- put a `memo` (`TfrxMemoView`) on that band
- set `[SUM(<reportdataset."NumericColumn">, MasterData1)]` as text, if you want to sum records only on current page
- set `[SUM(<reportdataset."NumericColumn">, MasterData1, 2)]` as text, if you want to sum records from current page and previous pages.

**Notes:**

You can use `"Report Summary"` band if you want to show aggregate information after all rows of your report.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it now.

Answer (score 1):

ColumnFooter1

```
 [SUM(<frxUserDataSet1."user_total_1">,MasterData1)]
```